# Mule - process file only when another is present

Tags: mule, endpoint, mule-studio, inbound

I have a Mule flow which processes files in an inbound folder that are named **AAA_[id_number].dat**. However, I need to configure Mule to only process this file when a corresponding file named **[id_number].dat** is also available. The second file indicates that the first is ready for processing.

Is there a way I can configure an inbound endpoint in Mule to only start processing the **AAA_** file when it's counterpart is present? The **[id_number].dat** file is purely for notification purposes, it should not be processed by Mule. The inbound endpoint has a regex filter to look for a file in the format AAA...

```
<!-- Mule Requester Config -->
<mulerequester:config name="muleRequesterConfig" doc:name="Mule Requester"/>

<!-- File Connectors -->
<file:connector name="inputTriggerConnector" pollingFrequency="100" doc:name="File"/>
<file:connector name="inputFileConnector" doc:name="File"/>
<file:connector name="outputFileConnector" doc:name="File"/>

<!-- File Endpoints -->
<file:endpoint name="inputFileEndpoint" path="src/test/input" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File">
    <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="\d{6}.dat" caseSensitive="true"/>  
</file:endpoint>

<!-- Trigger Flow -->
<flow name="triggerFlow" doc:name="triggerFlow">

    <file:inbound-endpoint ref="inputFileEndpoint" connector-ref="inputTriggerConnector" pollingFrequency="1000" doc:name="Input Trigger"/>

    <flow-ref name="mainFlow_StockB2C" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>       

</flow>

<!-- Main Flow -->
<flow name="mainFlow" doc:name="mainFlow">

    <mulerequester:request config-ref="muleRequesterConfig" resource="file://.../AAA_#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]?connector=inputFileConnector" timeout="6000" doc:name="Mule Requester"/>

    <DO SOMETHING WITH AAA_ FILE>

    <file:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="outputFileConnector" path="src/test/output" outputPattern="#[function:dateStamp].csv" responseTimeout="6000" doc:name="Output File"/>

</flow>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not filter set a file inbound filter for the [id_number].dat files (or one that excludes the AAA_ files), if those are only used for notification? Would make more sense in my opinion. You can then grab the file to be processed with the [requester module](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-module-requester) inside the flow, based on the originalFileName property.

Comment: Thanks @Anton, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Hi @Anton, I have a follow up question. How do I stop Mule from processing the [id_number].dat file? I only want the file with the AAA prefix to be processed by my flow. Currently if I drop the [id_number] file in my inbound location first it is processed and the AAA file is left untouched. I've edited my original question to include my XML.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Your xml is not runnable due to small mistakes and missing code, but apart from that it looks mostly like it should. The content of [id_number] file is largely ignored, and at the <DO SOMETHING WITH AAA_ FILE> point you should have the AAA file content available. You should see the file contents if you put <object-to-string-transformer/><logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO"/> after the mulerequester component.

Comment: currently if [id_number] is placed in the input directory before AAA_[id_number] then it is passed through the flow and into the output directory, so when an AAA_[id_number] file is dropped, nothing happens to it. I'm trying to prevent the [id_number] file from progressing past the first 'trigger' flow and remaining in the input directory until AAA_ appears.

Comment: That scenario doesn't quite match the "second file indicates that the first is ready for processing" description... I suggest you try to set up until-successful or some exception strategy to retry periodically when the AAA file is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this might help someone who needs it, you can create a custom filter and include your own filtering logic in there. More details from this blog [here](https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/connectivity-dev/using-advanced-file-filters-in-file-inbound-endpoint/)